# Addings horizontals line on each Bar using Highcarter in R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

This is my code:

```
data <- gapminder::gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Brazil') %>%
  mutate(life = rnorm(12,mean = 55,sd = 5),
         months = month.abb)
```

This is my chart:

```
 data%>%
      mutate(months = as_factor(months)) %>%
      mutate(index = rep(c(1,2),6), .before = everything()) %>%

      hchart(
        'column',
        names = 'SQUADS',
        hcaes(x = months,
              y = lifeExp,
              group = months),

        color = rep(c('#1B3D59','lightgray'),6),

        name = 'Sales',
        # groupPadding = 1.5,
        pointWidth = 20,
        showInLegend = FALSE
      )
```

I would like to add horizontal lines "--" on each bar that represents the values of `life` column to achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is with `errorbars`. Essentially, you'll make the low and high the same value, thus creating segments.

I've added one argument to your code for the `column` chart. You need `centerInCategory` otherwise the bars won't align with the error bars. Other than this one additional argument, your original code is the same as in your question.

When coding the new series, I used `life` as the position for the lines. Additionally, any specifications for spacing you add to the `column` you have to add to the `errorbar`, as well.

If you have any questions, let me know.

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

data <- gapminder::gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Brazil') %>%
  mutate(life = rnorm(12, mean = 55,sd = 5),
         months = month.abb)

data %>%
  mutate(months = as_factor(months)) %>%
  mutate(index = rep(c(1,2), 6), .before = everything()) %>%
  
  hchart('column',
         names = 'SQUADS', name = 'Sales', 
         hcaes(x = months, y = lifeExp, group = months),
         color = rep(c('#1B3D59','lightgray'), 6),
         pointWidth = 20, showInLegend = FALSE,
         centerInCategory = T) %>%                   # <--- I added this!
  hc_add_series(data, "errorbar",
                hcaes(x = months, y = life, low = life, high = life, 
                      group = months),
                pointWidth = 20, whiskerLength = 20, # widths set match column
                centerInCategory = T, showInLegend = F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@Kat 's solution is on all accounts much simpler and probably the way to go.

Below is my attempt which I believe offers more flexibility. I've set up a custom symbol that's used for the marker. Then added a line series with `lineWidth = 0` so only the marker is shown. Doing it this way plays more nicely with the tooltip. Also to center the columns you can use `groupPadding = .5`. In the JS loading function - I needed to manually update the symbol once the chart has rendered.

Let me know if you have any questions!

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

data = data %>%
  mutate(months = as.factor(months)) %>%
  mutate(index = rep(c(1,2),6), .before = everything())

highchart(type = "chart") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "categories", categories = unique(data2$months)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data, hcaes(x = months, y = lifeExp), type = "column", name = 'Sales',
    groupPadding = .5, 
    pointWidth = 20, 
    showInLegend = FALSE
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(data, hcaes(x = months, y = life), type = "line", name = "Life",
    lineWidth = 0, states = list(hover = list(lineWidthPlus = 0)),
    showInLegend = FALSE
  ) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    line = list(
      marker = list(
        symbol = 'line', 
        lineWidth = 3,
        radius = 12, 
        lineColor = "#000")
      ),
    column = list(
      colorByPoint = TRUE,
      colors = rep(c("#4f8ec2",'lightgray'), 6) 
    )
    ) %>%
  hc_chart(
    events = list(
      load = JS("function(){
        Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.line = function(x, y, w, h) {
                  return ['M',x ,y + w / 2,'L',x+h,y + w / 2];
        };
        this.series[1].update({marker: {symbol: 'line'}})
      }")
    )
  )
```

[image]